# Grep Text between pattern and space

Tags: sed, grep

I have data in below format.

```
sometext NAME=abc TIME_TAKEN
sometext NAME=xyz{123} REQUEST
```

I am trying to grep the data between Name and space . I want output in below format

```
 abc
 xyz{123}
```

I tried using sed along with cat like below but it is not working .

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/NAME=\(.*\)"\+[[:space:]]\+"/\1/g'

awk 'sub(/.*NAME= +/,"") && sub(/ +.*/,"")' test.txt
```

Regards

Comment: Why the double quotes? I don't see any in the input data.

Comment: It was erroring out without it so tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match everything before and after the assignment:

```
sed -ne 's/.* NAME=\(.*\) .*/\1/p' test.txt
```

Beware! It will extract the **last** `NAME=...` from each line.

Comment: This might return more than you expected, remember `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/.*\<NAME=(\S*).*/\1/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n` and turn on extended regexp `-E`.

Match a word `NAME`, followed by `=` and then any number of non-white spaced characters and return the any number of non-white spaced characters.

N.B. The replacement must replace the entire line, hence the `.*` at the start and end of the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command

```
cat test.txt | sed 's#.*NAME=\(.* \).*#\1#'
```

Explanation:

```
cat test.txt | sed 's# .*NAME=        \(.* \)                  .*      #\1#'
cat fileName | sed 's# All upto NAME= extract(upto any space)  skip all
```